# Erlang OTP supervisor

Tags: erlang, erlang-supervisor, gen-server

I'm working on Exercise 12-2 from the book Erlang Programming.  I have a module **db_server_otp** that implements an OTP gen_server behavior.  As a stand-alone module, I have tested it and it works as expected.  I now have to add a supervisor for it.  Based on the example in the chapter, I created a module **db_server_sup** as follows:

```
-module(db_server_sup).
-export([start/0,init/1]).
-behavior(supervisor).

start() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).

init(_Arguments) ->
    DbServerOtp = {db_server_otp,                %% Id
                   {db_server_otp, start, []},   %% child process
                   permanent,                    %% restart 
                   30000,                        %% shutdown (ms)
                   worker,                       %% type
                   {db_server_otp}},             %% required modules
    {ok, 
     {{one_for_all,           %% terminate all children and restart
       5,                     %% max of n restarts in MaxSeconds
       3600},                 %% MaxSeconds (s)
      [DbServerOtp]}}.        %% child process list
```

Both modules are located in the same directory, and I compiled both modules with .beam files are in the same working directory where I start the erlang shell.  With the erlang shell, however, I'm unable to start the supervisor.

```
Erlang R13B03 (erts-5.7.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:2] [rq:8] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V5.7.4  (abort with ^G)
1> c(db_server_otp).
./db_server_otp.erl:5: Warning: undefined callback function code_change/3 (behaviour 'gen_server')
./db_server_otp.erl:5: Warning: undefined callback function handle_info/2 (behaviour 'gen_server')
{ok,db_server_otp}
2> c(db_server_sup).
{ok,db_server_sup}
3> db_server_sup:start().
** exception exit: {start_spec,{invalid_modules,{db_server_otp}}}
```

Do I have to import the **db_server_otp** module?  If so, what functions must I import?  I am exporting all of my OTP methods in **db_server_otp**:

```
-module(db_server_otp).
-export([start/0,stop/0]).
-export([write/2,read/1,delete/1,match/1]).
-export([init/1,terminate/2,handle_cast/2,handle_call/3]).
-behavior(gen_server).
```

Comment: Whatever the problem here importing will **NOT** help. It is **pure syntactic sugar** which allows you to call a function in another module without having to write the module name. It has absolutely no semantic meaning. Many say you should not use it as it lessens clarity.

Comment: I think I can agree with that statement regarding clarity.  Certainly in my C++ code I'd rather write out the namespace so that it is easy to locate the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'required modules' is supposed to be a list, not a tuple.

Try using:

```
DbServerOtp = {db_server_otp,                %% Id
               {db_server_otp, start, []},   %% child process
               permanent,                    %% restart 
               30000,                        %% shutdown (ms)
               worker,                       %% type
               [db_server_otp]},             %% required modules
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the above error message.  I know get '** exception exit: shutdown', but at least this is some progress.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dr.Watson: What does `db_server_otp:start/0` return? Have you tried to call `db_server_sup:start` inside a `catch` to get the actual error value. It would make it easier to see whether the error comes when starting the supervisor or because it dies later. The `shutdown` reason is used by OTP when stopping processes.

Comment: @Dr.Watson: A follow on question: what happens when you `db_server_otp:start/0` from the shell? Does it exit? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

A stylistic convention: seeing the start functions in `db_server_sup` and `db_server_otp` both create links you should call them `start_link`. It is a common convention.